# The inclusions $\iota_A:A \hookrightarrow X $ induce the final topology $\mathcal{T}'$ of $X$. Show that $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a space and $\mathcal{A}$ a collection of subsets of $X$ that has the subspace topology. The inclusions $\iota_A:A \hookrightarrow X $ induce the final topology $\mathcal{T}'$ of $X$. Show that $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$.

The topology $\mathcal{T}'$ makes all the inclusion maps continuous. So if $U \in \mathcal{T}$, then $U$ is open in $X$ and if $U \cap A = \emptyset$ for any $ A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $\iota_A^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$ but this is open so $U \in \mathcal{T}'$.

If $U \cap A \ne \emptyset$, then $\iota_A^{-1}(U)=U \cap A$ which is by definition in $\mathcal{T}'$.

My question is that do I need to consider the case where $U \cap A = \emptyset$? Since if $U$ is open in $X$, then it could be possible that $U$ doesn't intersect any of the $A$'s in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Let $\mathcal T_A$ be the induced topology on $A.$ Do you know $i_A:(A,\mathcal T_A)\to(X,\mathcal T)$ is continuous for each $A\subseteq X?$ But this means $i_A^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$ for each $A.$

Comment: I know this, but I'm wondering what happens when $\iota_A^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$. So when $U$ and $A$ doesn't meet.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is always open. So why would that be a problem?

Comment: Essentially, you don’t need to take the two cases where $A\cap U=\emptyset$ and $\neq\emptyset.$ The definition of the induced topology on $A$ already handles it.

Comment: If $B$ is any set which does not intersect with any $A,$ then $B\in\mathcal T’.$ That’s true whether $B\in\mathcal T$ or not. What this shows is that the restriction of $\mathcal T’$ to $X\setminus \bigcup\mathcal A$ is the discrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the subspace topology, all $\iota_A: (A,\mathcal{T}_A) \to (X,\mathcal{T}$ are continuous.

Now if $U \in \mathcal{T}$, we thus know that $\iota^{-1}[U]$ is open in $(X, \mathcal{T}_A)$. It doesn't matter what $A \cap U$ is we know by definition that $\iota^{-1}[U]= U \cap A \in \mathcal{T}_A$, no special case for $\emptyset$ is needed. So $\mathcal{T}$ is **some** topology that makes all $\iota_A$ continuous while by definition of the final topology $\mathcal{T}'$ is the *maximal* such topology, hence the inclusion $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal T'$ follows trivially.